# Running a modal after another modal

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently making a Discord bot which includes a get-to-know-you form that has more than 5 questions, so I had to split the form into 2 modals and show the second modal after running the first modal. This is my current code (I got it from the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/modals.html)):

```
// ... Set up bot

// The button to open the modal
const verifybutton = new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId('formpart1')
    .setLabel('Open Modal')
    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);

const row = new ActionRowBuilder() .addComponents(verifybutton);

// Show the button when client loads
client.on('ready', () => { channel = client.channels.fetch('<My channel id>') .then(channel => channel.send( {components: [row]} )) });

// Detects when button is clicked
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
    
    const modal = new ModalBuilder()
        .setCustomId('formpart1')
        .setTitle('Form part 1');
    
    const question1 = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId('question1')
        .setLabel("Question 1:")
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
    const question1actionrow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(question1);
    
    const question2 = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId('question2')
        .setLabel("Question 2:")
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
    const question2actionrow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(question2);
    
    const question3 = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId('question3')
        .setLabel("Question 3:")
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
    const question3actionrow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(Question3);
    
    const question4 = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId("question4")
        .setLabel("Question 4:")
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
    const question4actionrow= new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(Question4);
    
    const question5 = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId("question5")
        .setLabel("Question 5:")
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
    const question5actionrow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(question5);
    
    // Add questions to modal
    modal.addcomponents(question1actionrow, question2actionrow, question3actionrow, question4actionrow, question5actionrow);
    
    // Show the modal
    await interaction.showModal(modal); // This works

});

// Detects when modal is submitted
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;
    
    if (interaction.customId === 'formpart1') {

        const modal1 = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId("formpart2")
            .setTitle('Form Part 2');;
    
        const question6 = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId("question6")
            .setLabel("Question 6:")
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
        const question6actionrow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(question6);
    
        const question7 = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId("question7")
            .setLabel("Question 7:")
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
        const question7actionrow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(question7);
    
        // Add questions to modal
        modal1.addcomponents(question6actionrow, question7actionrow);
        
        // Show the modal
        await interaction.showModal(modal1); // This dosen't work
    }
});
```

I have ensured that the format of the code in the second part is the same as the first part. Yet, when I open the first modal, it works, but when I click `submit` to open the second modal, it did not work. How can I fix this?

I have tried doing the following:

- Changing `await interaction.showmodal(modal1)` to `interaction.showmodal(modal1)`
- Adding an `interaction.reply("Submitted")` to close the modal first, before opening the second modal with `interaction.showmodal(modal1)`
- Changing `interaction.showmodal(modal1)` to `interaction.reply("Submitted!")`  --> Works, but it's not what I want.
- Going online to find solutions (which none of them worked)

I expected that when I clicked "submit" to the first part of the modal, the modal would close, and the second part modal would open. However, I got this error:

`TypeError: interaction.showModal is not a function`

Comment: You cannot show a modal after another, it seems this is a limitation placed by the Discord API